# Getting jar content

Tags: java, jar, zip, 7zip, powergrep

I'm trying to open some .jar archieve and get files from it.
What i've got now:

1. As i know `.jar==.zip`, so i used **7zip**. It opens my jar and says that **headers broken** and still succeeded extraction.
2. I used standard Oracle jdk utility `jar tvf my.jar` and got this:

   `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:120)
           at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1115)
           at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:293)
           at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)`
3. I searched the web and found **PowerGREP5** tool that opens this jar.

**jar** archieve was extracted from parent **.zip** archieve, that had valid CRC and unziped without any errors

*Problem goes here*:

Contents, that i got from 7zip **complitely differs** from PowerGREP. Pls help me to understand how could this happen.

Comment: Java only supports the DEFLATE and STORE compression methods. The file likely uses another compression method, or is not actually a ZIP file, or is corrupt (aka "broken").

Comment: @Andreas, how can i know which copression method is used? And why content, that i got from 7z and powerGREP differs?

Answer (score -1):

you have miss hyphen(-) in before tvf, use bellow command

```
 jar -tvf my.jar
```

Comment: Just tested with -. Got exactly the same output as i listed in question